# position access fail on setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-adapter

I'm doing an android app and i'm having problems to get the position to know which elemenent at list i'll erase.
My code look like this:

```
final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaPlantilla);
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador_fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);

lista.setAdapter(adaptador_fileList);

      lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,   long id)  {
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mis_cervezas.this);   


                ad.setCancelable(true);
                ad.setTitle("Opciones");
                ad.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);


                ad.setItems(R.array.opciones_mis_cervezas, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        switch(item){
                        case 0:// Ver Ficha
                            break;
                        case 1://Tutorial
                            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"He apretado Comenzar Tutorial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast2.show();
                            break;
                        case 2://Eliminar
                            lista.removeViewAt(position); // error line
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                ad.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                         // Do something with the selection
                    }
                });
                ad.show();
            }
        });
```

I need to know how can i erase one element. The code don't let me use position so i need to know how can i get the position.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The onItemClick seems to be giving you a position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object item = adaptador_fileList.getItem(position);

adaptador_fileList.remove(item);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();